# Compare javafx imageview images?

Tags: java, javafx

Hi just wondering about javafx images cause im making a tic tac toe app and it would seem that comparing the images always fires the win screen for me. i have tried a few approach's but cannot figure it out. so i assume im camparing images the wrong.

ive tried the following ( all iv objects are ImageView)

```
iv21.getImage() == iv22.getImage() && iv22.getImage() == iv23.getImage
```

and

```
iv11.getImage().equals(iv12) && iv12.equals(iv13)
```

is this wrong?
I find it strange cause after every move the win screen appears which is strange cause all the imageviews.getImage() = null at that point.
could it be a loading issue?

Comment: Use an array or some other structure to keep up with the game state.

Comment: I am guessing that you can set the ids of the nodes to x or o. `imageView.setId("x");`, then check for wins based on `imageView.getId();`.

Comment: If you use an image or `null` for empty fields does not matter, since `null == null` and `emptyImage == emptyImage`... I guess this results in a win for one of the players... Also `image1 == image2` and `image1.equals(image2)` will yield `true` if and only if the images are the same instances (with the former also working for `null` values). `iv11.getImage().equals(iv12) && iv12.equals(iv13)` will never work since comparing `ImageView`s with `Image`s will never yield `true`. However we cannot be sure what's causing the issue with the amount of code you posted...